# node-config multiple configuration files

Tags: node.js, node-config

I am looking at this https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config, and it seems to do everything I need. However I am wondering if it's possible to specify multiple config files based on their categories.

Is this possible to do this?

```
./config
   default-aws.json or aws-default.json
   production-aws.json or aws-production.json
   db-default.json
   db-production.json
```

etc..

so the config files can be smaller? I know we could make a giant config that has all of those required in different sections. eg

```
{
   "aws": {
      "kinesis": "my-stream"
       ....
    },
    "db": {
       "host": "my-host"
        ...
    }
}
```

Anyone has any ideas if this is doable using node-config or different library that works similar to node-config?

Thanks & regards
Tin

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is NO. node-config doesn't support this (As @Mark's response).

The simplest way to do this using node-config is to use JavaScript as config files (https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Configuration-Files#javascript-module---js). This way you still get most of the benefits of using node-config. Then you can simply include other files inside them (https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Special-features-for-JavaScript-configuration-files#including-other-files)

Note that it would be a bit harder to use the multiple config files and overrides for the inner files.

A slightly more complex implementation can use the utility class in config which actually allows you to directly read a specific folder using the same patterns that node-config uses internally (https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Using-Config-Utilities#loadfileconfigsdirectory).
In that case you would probably want to combine all the files to a single config by setting them on the config object before the first call to get (https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Configuring-from-an-External-Source).

Answer (score 3):

I'm a maintainer of `node-config`. The next version will support a feature to declare multiple `NODE_ENV` values, separated by a comma.

So if you were doing development in the cloud, you could declare a "development" environment followed by a "cloud" environment.

First the development config would be loaded, followed by the "cloud" config.

The related pull request is [#486](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/pull/486).

Answer (score 2):

I use [nconf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nconf). It lets you read multiple configuration files into the same object. Here is an example:

```
var nconf = require('nconf');

//read the config files; first parameter is a required key
nconf.file('aws', {file: 'default-aws.json'});
nconf.file('db', {file: 'db-default.json'});

console.log(nconf.get('aws:kinesis'));
console.log(nconf.get('db:host'));
```

default-aws.json:

```
{
  "aws": {
    "kinesis": "my-stream"
  }
}
```

db-default.json:

```
{
  "db": {
    "host": "my-host"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How would you get the entire merged config (default/prod) as json in nconf? I know we can do JSON.stringify(nconf.get("aws:kinesis")), but how about the root node without having to know what the root node is?
 and also how do you override the value for "aws:kinesis" with an environment variable in this case?

Comment: Perhaps you can read and process each file individually:

nconf.file({file: cFile1});
console.log(nconf.get('aws:kinesis'));
console.log(nconf.get('key'));

nconf.file({file: cFile2});
console.log(nconf.get('db:host'));
console.log(nconf.get('key'));

I know this is basically like working with one nconf object, so it may not be exactly what you want.